# Need to map 0-5V DAC output to 0-10V output

Tags: amplifier, spi, dac, level-shifting

I am using a [TLV5618](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv5618a.pdf) to take a 16 bit SPI package to produce a voltage between 0-5V with 12 bits of resolution (4 control bits).

Now I need to shift this signals from 0-5v to a 0-10v signal. I do not have negative power supplies, I have 10V, 12V, and 24V supplies available to me. Is there any simple circuit that can do this in a linear fashion?
i.e. 0v = 0v+-10counts and 5v = 10v+-10counts

I am attempting to read these signals by a ADC on a plc so it is important that it outputs voltage from 0-10v and it doesn't have any problems getting to 0+/-10counts or 10+/-10counts, which makes me think opamp circuits are generally not going to be an option.

[image: 0-5v SPI DAC]

Comment: Just curious, why are you converting from the digital domain to analog and back to digital? You realize you will have some errors, right? Off by 1 due to quantization at the least. That being said, what is the maximum error you can tolerate?

Comment: 12 bits gives you a count of 0 to 4095 so even assuming a perfect DAC each count is approx 1.22mV on a 0 to 5V scale.  Doubling the range makes each count approx 2.44mV.  You may be able to tweak the endpoints to 0.1mV but you can't achieve this accuracy across the range.

Comment: The data signals to the D/A are all one way so if the PLC can't read it directly I'd just use a microcontroller to convert it into a format it can.

Comment: I just want a solution that gets me close to 0 and close to 10 within 0.1 Volts, doesn't need to be super accurate. I am simulating PLC signals, so that is why I need to go from Digital - Analog - Digital. 

I am simulating a system digitally, then evaluating. Sending SPI signals from my macbook is much simpler than manually trimming a POT.

Comment: If you are working with PLC signals and industrial equipment, I'd suggest just picking up a signal conditioner, [like this one](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/process_control_-a-_measurement/signal_conditioners/dc_voltage,_current_or_potentiometer_input/fc-33) that can convert 0-5VDC to 0-10VDC. Or if you wanted to get a little fancier, you could just get a [cheap PLC with analog outputs](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/programmable_controllers/click_series_plcs_(stackable_micro_brick)/plc_units/c0-02dd1-d) that can simulate better.

Comment: We work with Android tablets instead of HMIs so the idea is we need to simulate signals to test the tablet code. It just isn't practical to actually run the equipment to test the tablet code at this point, it would be way more time consuming to do that. So we are going to work out the initial bugs, in a simulated environment. So the PLC just needs to operate close to how it will operate in the field.

Answer (score 2):

Standard op amp with a gain of 2, you will need a rail to rail op amp, you will also want some pulldown, e.g. 2K to ground to ensure it really can get that close to 0V without issue,

I would recommend the 12V supply, to give you some head room to supply current for the pulldown resistor,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2xCk3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Even rail-rail-output opamps need headroom, if output current must be supplied. So go for the +12 rail.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf yes... That is exactly what I have written and shown in the schematic?

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need! But can you explain how R3 will get me close to zero?

Comment: part of the issue with op amp outputs is when they get close to there supply rails the resistance of the output begins to climb towards infinity, by having the output constantly pulled towards ground this improves how low the output can reach for any leakage currents on the output, at the cost of having to consume some more power for every other part of the output range.

Comment: Oh, thanks, that makes a little more sense. Is there a name for leakage currents on the output end. Does this configuration affect the input bias currents, or do they remain the same?

Comment: http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu018/tidu018.pdf Its a fraction of a supply current. This only improves how close it can get. Its not a garenteed 0v. However for 12 bits over 10V. That is 2.4mV per step. So a low supply current op amp with a pulldown should get you under this. Input bias and offset voltage add to this. But its not that hard to find a precision op amp with low bias and low offset.

Answer (score 0):

A simple non-inverting amplifier with a single-supply or RR I/O precision (low Vos TCVos and high gain) op-amp will meet that requirement, at least in theory. The low output offset is not a problem if it is not required to sink current, otherwise you would need to make a negative supply rail to get nominal 0V out.

However, 100uV error at 10V is 10ppm and it is very unlikely your DAC has anything like that accuracy or stability, not to mention linearity, however a precision amplifier with a precision Z-foil matched resistor network (eg 10k/10k) can easily reach that level of gain accuracy (maybe with a slight gain trim) and stability. But if your DAC output is off by 0.2%, the amplified output will be similarly inaccurate.